# Running python script in nvidia cuda docker

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I downloaded and set up the docker https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker and the image https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker.

Test case works:

```
docker run --gpus all -it --rm tensorflow / tensorflow: latest-gpu \
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print (tf.reduce_sum (tf.random.normal ([1000, 1000])))"
```

What should I do to make the program written in Visual Studio Code run in docker instead of python (locally installed)?

```
docker run --gpus all -it --rm tensorflow / tensorflow: latest-gpu \
    python /home/something.py
```

It doesn't work because what I understand this is the path in the docker and not on the host machine. Should I build a new docker image with the program inside? I wanted to use the downloaded image without changing it.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to mount your **local directory** [where visual code has saved your python file] on docker. Here is a working example -

docker run --gpus all **-v <your_directory_where_visual_code_has_saved_python_file>:/home** -it --rm tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu 
python /home/something.py

My working example that i tried -

`docker run --gpus all -v /home/ubuntu/test:/home/test  -it tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu python /home/jitest.py`

Comment: Thank you for quick replay. It's working :D  docker run --gpus all -v /home/fractal/Documents:/home  -it tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu python /home/tensorgputest.py

Answer (score 2):

To make your program run on docker, you have many options :

1. in your Dockerfile copy the code inside the docker
2. you can mount the folder containing your python code as docker volume [recommended]

for more information check [this](https://becominghuman.ai/how-to-build-a-deep-learning-server-based-on-docker-bea70b8bd2c7) medium articles